# Comparison in string literal results in inspecified behavior - C++

Tags: c++, string, arguments

I'm using eclipse.
I declared `#define OUTPUT_FLAG "-o"`
and then, I have the main : `int main(int argc, char **argv)`
after that I write:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i+=2)
    {
        if(argv[i]==INPUT_FLAG)
        {
            cout<<"input flag\n";
            input_file=argv[i+1];
        }
    }
```

and there I get the error on the subject. Can you help me here?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compare strings with `==` in C++. You either have to use `strcmp` or convert them to `std::string`s *and then* use the `==` operator. That is, either:

```
if (!strcmp(argv[i], INPUT_FLAG))
```

or

```
if (std::string(argv[i]) == INPUT_FLAG)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare C strings (`char *`) using the `==` operator, as that operator only checks for pointer equality (rather than dereferencing the pointer and comparing each character one by one). Use `strcmp()`, or convert the string in `argv[]` to a C++ `string` type first.